# Absolute path for URL

Tags: symfony

I have urls such as

```
http://localhost/test/web/app_dev.php/

http://localhost/test/web/app_dev.php/profile/change-password

http://localhost/test/web/app_dev.php/member/form/test
```

I would like to get absolute path for these url

I have used often uses absolute path for images or assets such as

```
{{ asset('bundles/acmedemo/images/title_contact.gif') }}
```

but those URL are not under some bundle directory.
What way should I use to make absolute path for those URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of url can be written using `{{ path() }}`.

For example:

```
<a href="{{ path('profile-change-password') }}">
  Change password
</a>
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls-from-a-template

Comment: THank you !! it is basic function I should know.

Answer (score 1):

If you need absolute path then ...

```
{{ url() }}
```

For example:

```
<a href="{{ url('my_home_route') }}">
  Home
</a>
```